# Cron several script every 5 minutes with 10 second between each script

Tags: cron

I have several file setup in my `crontab`, all those scripts must run every 5 minutes.
The problem comes when those script need to much CPU and IO at a time and the machine become unavailable.

To mitigate this effect, I'd like to know if there's an option to put 10 seconde between each script start. It should leverage the dramatic load raise (more than 40 for a monocore) we issue when all those scripts have too much data to process.

Is it possible to somehow schedule script every 5 minutes in crontab without starting at the beginning of the fifth minute for all script ?

Comment: run script1 at 1,6,11 ... , script2 at 2,7,12, script3 ate 3,8,13, .. rather than use */5 in crontab.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create one cron entry that is:

```
*/5 * * * * processA ; sleep 10 ; processB ; sleep 10 ; process C
```

However, I recommend against this.

I wouldn't use cron at all.  Cron is not that smart.  If you tell it to run a job every 5 minutes, and the job takes 6 minutes to run, you will get 2 processes running.  By the end of the day you'll have dozens or hundreds of these processes running at the same time.

A safer way is to not use cron. Instead, run a script like this.  Use systemd or /etc/init.d scripts to turn it into a "service" that is always running:

```
while true ; do
   processA
   sleep 10
   processB
   sleep 10
   processC
   sleep 600
done
```

A longer explanation can be found here:

[How not to use Cron](http://everythingsysadmin.com/2014/02/how-not-to-use-cron.html)

Comment: interesting point of view

Answer (score 2):

There is no option is cron to get to units of seconds. Instead, make use of `sleep`.

For example, in case those are all shell scripts:

1. Set the cron for the 1st script as usual.
2. Add `sleep 10` to the second script so that the actual execution starts after 10 seconds.
3. Add `sleep 20` to the third... and so on.

Comment: Modifying the scripts to have "sleep 10" in them seems like a bad "separation of duties".  It means scripts can't be used without the sleep.  It is better to run `processA ; sleep 10 ; processB`

Comment: `* * * * * /path/to/script1.sh
* * * * * sleep 10 ; /path/to/script2.sh
* * * * * sleep 20 ; /path/to/script3.sh`