# systemd service to skip overlapping runs

Tags: rhel, systemd, oracle-linux, systemd-timer

I am trying to schedule a service using systemd on Oracle Linux Server 7.7.

The use-case is simple; the timer needs to run the service in every hour (between 2PM and 9AM) - but, *only if that is not running already*. By [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/203262/189684), I thought it is the case by default.

So, the **expectation** would be:

- 2:00: timer starts the service - service begins to run and let's say it runs for 90 mins this time
- 3:00: since the service is still running, **do nothing this time**
- 4:00: service has completed around 3:30, so start the service again - service runs for 20 mins now
- 5:00: timer starts the service again
- ...

However, the **current result** is:

- 2:00: timer starts the service - service begins to run and let's say it runs for 90 mins this time
- 3:00: since the service is still running, do nothing
- **3:30: the service completes, so it gets started again, immediately**
- ...

Could someone help me with this?

Thanks, guys!

---

my timer:

```
[Unit]
Description=Run service between 02-21 (inclusive) every hour

[Timer]
# the 02..21 syntax didn't work on this distribution, but I am open to suggestions to simplify it :) 
OnCalendar=*-*-* 02,03,04,05,06,07,08,09,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21:00:00
Unit=test-service.service

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

my service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Service for testing purposes

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/opt/apps/long-running-service
ExecStart=/opt/apps/long-running-service
Restart=no
KillSignal=SIGINT

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```